# Сохранение большого массива вне оперативной памяти в рамках одного процесса

Tags: php

У нас в момент интеграции скрипт собирает большой объем данных в массив (примерно 600 МБ), далее, идет работа с этими данными. Данные храним в массиве для быстрого доступа к необходимым полям по ключу (с целью оптимизации времени работы скрипта).

Сейчас возникла необходимость, в промежутке, когда вы собираем массив всех данных и  процесса работы с этим массивом, произвести некоторые ресурсозатратные операции (с точки зрения использования оперативной памяти).

Визуально это выглядит таким образом:

```
Функция_формирования_массива; - тут сразу 600 МБ под массив уходит
Запускаем_новый_функционал;
Работа_с_большим_массивом;
```

Требуется, в момент `Запускаем_новый_функционал;` каким-то образом освободить оперативку от этих 600 МБ.. После того, как выполнится `Запускаем_новый_функционал;` снова вернуть данные в массив.

Какие есть средства это реализовать максимально быстро по скорости?

Есть ли какие-то средства в php, чтобы бы данные из оперативки (массивы или объекты) сохранить на диск и потом забрать оттуда?

В голову приходит только вариант с файлом.. Сериализовать и  записать в файл, потом считать оттуда.

Какие есть еще варианты?

Comment: SimpleSHM, shmop_open - ничего пока про это не знаю. Но может в этом направлении нужно смотреть?

Comment: Redis, Memcache?..

Comment: @Streletz а они разве не оперативку используют?

Comment: А, Вы их планируете ставить на тот же сервер?

Comment: @Streletz да, мне в рамках 1 скрипта, нужно временно большой массив из оперативки куда-нибудь запихнуть, чтобы освободить память под другой процесс, а далее вернуть все обратно.

Comment: В рамках 1 скрипта нельзя подключиться к другому серверу?

Comment: @Streletz у нас нету другого сервера. В будущем возможно подключим. Сейчас нужно решить на одном сервере. Наверное пока придется в файл (или бд) записывать сериализованный массив и вытаскивать... пока вариантов не вижу.

Comment: В ответе есть ещё варианты.

Comment: если у вас массив этот не используется в новом функционале, то эти операции нельзя местами то поменять?

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов на самом деле много:

- Redis, Memcache на отдельном сервере;
- Пакетная загрузка данных (грузить не все 600 МБ сразу, а частями, например, по 100 МБ);
- Хранить данные в БД (во всяком случае работать будет быстрее, чем с файлом);
- Уже упомянутые Вами, временные файлы;
- Докупить памяти серверу (на худой конец).

Всё это первое, что пришло на ум. Что будет лучше, нужно уже смотреть исходя из задачи и особенностей скрипта.

Comment: Спасибо понял. 
А у вас был опыт работы с Redis ?
Можно ли его настроить, что часть оперативки выделяется с 1 сервера, а чуть с другого ? Это сложно настраивать? 

Можно пожалуйста пример, или где почитать о том, как на отдельном сервере поставить Redis, и работать с ним?

Comment: Можно объединить ресурсы нескольких серверов под Redis. Но, для этого нужно поднимать кластер.

Comment: Для 600 МБ достаточно 1 выделенного сервера (если не брать самые дешёвые с 1 ГБ или 512 МБ RAM), если сервера, где выполняется скрипт слабый.